# Why am I getting SQLSyntaxErrorException creating a stored procedure in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm not sure why I'm getting errors here. I'm just trying to create a stored procedure which does a select.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCustomerOrders(cust_id varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT c.Customer_ID, c.Company_Name, o.ID Order_ID,
      o.Name AS Description, o.Date_Paid, o.Created AS DateCreated, o.PAID
        FROM ORDERS o
        JOIN Customers c ON o.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
   WHERE c.Customer_ID = :cust_id
END
```

When I try this I get

> SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 9, column 1; END

So I add a semi-colon:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCustomerOrders(cust_id varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT c.Customer_ID, c.Company_Name, o.ID Order_ID,
      o.Name AS Description, o.Date_Paid, o.Created AS DateCreated, o.PAID
        FROM ORDERS o
        JOIN Customers c ON o.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
   WHERE c.Customer_ID = :cust_id;
END
```

And I get:

> SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 8, column 34; ;

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [Language Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html). In PSQL clause "INTO" is mandatory for SELECTs.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was used to MSSQL where it just happens directly. Good to know.

Comment: @sproketboy you would probably also want to read about `FOR` and `SUSPEND` in PSQL. And then you would probably want to remove this stored procedure altogether. Creating such SPs just prohibit any SQL optimization on joins, so would be rather wrong practice in Interbase/Firebird lineage. You would hardly advice to cargocult Firebird hacks upon MS SQL without thinking, would you? Same about copycatting MS SQL hacks to Firebird. If you really-really need abstraction layer in SQL rather than in application then use `VIEW`, albeit they do not have parameters